Pain in the little finger of the left hand during the playing of two notes at the same time
I am a beginner guitar player, but I am able to play many of the classical guitar music that I have to play one note at a time without much difficulty. However, I just tried to play the Minute in G from this YouTube tutorial. Here is the screenshot of the first part of the music:

I used the suggested fingers for my left hand. As you can see from the tablature, many of the double notes require the pinky finger (4th) of the left hand. When I played two notes at the same time where one of my fingers is the 4th finger of the left hand, I felt pain in my pinky finger because I press the string harder with this finger to get an optimal sound. I'm wondering if this is normal and if I would get used to it after doing it every day, or if I am doing something wrong. By the way, as I mentioned before, I do not have enough experience in playing music that requires playing two notes at once. I haven't even learned how to play chords properly. So maybe it is normal that my pinky finger hurts when I play double notes?
Actually, it is my fingertip that hurts when I play it, and it is likely to not be a serious issue.

Seems to me you're not playing double notes, but two consecutive notes. That's normal in guitar (and any other instrumental) playing.  Pinky is the weakest finger, so is being asked to do a lot. Please learn your chords, which will then make your life so much more simple, as your fingers will go to  a lot of these sort of shapes automatically.

@Tim Thanks for the suggestions, I am going to learn chords soon.

Are you properly curling your fingers when pressing, or are they flat? The latter will cause high strain on the joints, and should be avoided.

The only way to truly know if you’re doing something wrong would be to watch you play, either in person or a video. That may not be necessary if you take a few things into account. If you freeze frame the video where the guitarist is playing two notes simultaneously and try to mimic the hand position you see in a mirror chances are you’re on the right track.
There are a few other things for you to consider:
The pinky is the smallest and weakest finger, so it takes more time to develop equal strength and dexterity between it and your other fingers. The tip of the pinky also has the smallest surface area so when you press hard, it will be more painful than it will be with other fingers. As you play more, the skin between the tip of your finger and the bone will toughen and you will be able to hold notes with it more comfortably. The muscles in your pinky will also get stronger which also is helpful.
Another thing to be aware of is that the pinky is not required to hold the notes it plays for the entire bar like the bass note does. You can release it after the duration that is written so you are not holding those notes for an unnecessarily long time.
Practice playing individual notes with your pinky in this way: Play a note, say D on the B string but play it so that so lightly that you don’t get any sound. Gradually increase the pressure as you continuously pluck the string until at first you get a buzzy sound, and then a clear sound. When the clear sound comes out that tells you the amount of pressure you need to get a good tone. You don’t really have to squeeze harder than that. There are many instances where we press too hard with the left hand without thinking and it is not necessary. On the contrary, it can be detrimental because you are creating unnecessary tension in your hand by squeezing too hard.
A useful exercise for practicing developing your pinky strength with this piece is to only play the downbeats and sustain them for three beats. You will not always be playing two notes at once with your left hand or even your pinky, but it will get you used to the feeling of the double notes. An added benefit to this is you can clearly hear the harmony of the song. In the second repeated section where there are 3 quarter note chords per measure like bars 22 & 23, play them all. Below is an 4 bar example of what I mean, Good luck to you and kudos for attempting this piece as a beginner!


+1 for most of this - ignoring the hint of calluses!

@Tim I remember your question and subsequent discussion about calluses from a few years back very well!

If it's your finger tip that hurts when playing two notes (as in the question), then you won't actually be using your fingertip to press down two strings. You'll be using the pad of the pinky to achieve that. So, not sure where the question is going, whether  you mean two notes consecutively, or two notes simultaneously.
Either way, knowing your chords is absolutely essential for this kind of play. Most of what is needed will be partial chords, so knowing the shapes will help tremendously in not only the physical playing, but also the reading of the dots, and even the tab.

In almost every guitar chord phrasing endeavor, particularly when learning new pieces, a little bit of discomfort is to be expected. With repetition comes a comfortable adaptation though, and improved digit strength will overcome most worries.
Now, that said, pain is another matter.
If what you are working on isn’t considered a seriously difficult piece, and you feel noticeable pain, then it’s best to step back and evaluate your situation.
If you are seated whilst playing, ensure there are no arms on the chair to restrict the free movement of your elbows, wrists, and hands. Restriction often lead to awkward phrasing and yes, pain.
Consult your family doctor.
How old are you?
Is there a chance that you have arthritis in your fingers?
It's best to proceed carefully.
Get some medical advice, at the very least.

Thanks for the answer. Actually, it is my fingertip that hurts when I play it, and it is likely to not be a serious issue.

Ah, fingertip then.
That's a different matter.
Good luck with it!

I'm by no means a professional guitarist but I agree with the other fellows in regards to the pain in the little finger. That'll happen and it's a good thing. It suggests that your incorporating it, which is essential. Once it heals or stops hurting and you begin again you'll eventually notice calluses and that's normal as well. You'll notice your fingers becoming more and more acclimated to what your doing.

As I keep saying, calluses are not normal, and shouldn't happen, unless you play 12 hrs a day - when the tips will probably bleed before anything else!

@Tim Isn't some thickening of the skin normal?  I play mandolin and electric bass on and off, and whenever I play either for more than a few minutes after several days off, I always notice the skin (re)thickening over the following day or so.

@gidds - There are so many mentions of calluses on this site, sort of a 'badge of honour'. Playing for 60+ yrs, bass and guitar, I don't see any on my fingers. Maybe I'm different, although I don't remember any students with them either. Well set up instruments, pressing only as hard as necessary help. For pull-offs, I guess calluses may be detrimental, but how would I know..?

@Tim Maybe your skin is thicker/tougher to start with?

@gidds - you're not the first to say I have broad shoulders and thick skin...

IT IS normal if your new to playing the guitar, wow

As a guitar teacher my impression is that everything you have described is entirely normal. Keep up the good work!
Using the fourth finger of the left hand is a necessary skill for any guitarist who wants to progress beyond a beginner level. For my students at that stage I give them a set of basic exercises involving the C major and G major chords. I have uploaded 3 sample chord diagrams and you should study the fingerings carefully. You will see that there is one fingering for the C chord, but two different options for the G chord.
I demonstrate both options to my students and show them that playing G with fingers 123 means a much bigger transition for the first finger. (between string 2 and 6). But if they can learn G with fingers 234, then the only movement is fingers 2 and 3. They hold a stable shape, and they only have to move up and down one string (between 5 and 6). Furthermore, both finger 1 and finger 4 don't have to move at all. In time you will learn to let them hover over the note that completes the chord, and simply press/lift as required.
So as you practice, don't focus just on finger 4. Focus on all the fingers together, and in particular understand how and where they move. I would not get you to practice finger 4 first. I would get you to practice finger 2 and 3 working together. Create a C chord. Then lift finger 1 off the second string. Now you are just pressing 2 fingers (technically a Cmaj7 chord). Move them together, upwards, from strings 54 to strings 65. Now you are in the G chord position, and would complete the G chord if you pressed your 4th finger on string 1. But don't do that. Just focus on the combined movement of fingers 2 and 3, up and down, up and down. Get those two fingers going well, and the rest will follow.




All well and good, except the question is not actually about movement between chords G and C.

There is at least one more fingering for G, and a couple more for C - all of which need to be shown to beginner students!

Absolutely, and based on these comments I haven't been as clear as I should. Sorry about that. My key point is that these chord shapes function as good example shapes for developing the use of the fourth finger. Of course there are many other exercises, chords, note patterns and so on. But this one seemed useful in the light of the OP's reference to Bach's Minuet in G.
